# Upload original firmware to HID Arduino

Tags: firmware

I recently was playing around with Arduino and using dfu-programmer reflashed ATMega16u2 to make the computer think it was a keyboard device.

Well, I wish to put the original Arduino firmware back on, but now dfu-programmer says the device is not present.

The Arduino is listed under `/dev/hidraw5` on Ubuntu. Typing `lsusb` gives the following output for Arduino keyboard:

```
Bus 004 Device 008: ID 03eb:2042 Atmel Corp. LUFA Keyboard Demo Application
```

I tried erasing with the command:

```
sudo dfu-programmer atmega16u2:4,8 erase
```

and got

```
dfu-programmer: no device present.
```

Is there a way to target `/dev/hidraw5` using dfu-programmer? Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Very sorry!  But I actually figured this out on my own.  I needed to reset by briefly bridging the reset pin with ground near the USB connector.  Then typed

```
sudo dfu-programmer atmega16u2 erase
```

and I'm happy again.